# Adding common project as a dependency to quarkus projects and expose its classes as a CDI bean

Tags: java, quarkus

I have a simple maven project

```
 <dependency>
       <groupId>xyz</groupId>
       <artifactId>common</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

which includes common methods(some string operations etc..). And i would like to use it inside of quarkus project by injecting its classes as CDI bean.Could i add this maven project as a dependency to my quarkus project via traditional way in **pom.xml** or should i convert it to quarkus extension? I have searched for it but there is no good enough documentation as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The documentation regarding CDI / Bean Discovery should get you started: https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference#bean_discovery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the dependency contains a `META-INF/beans.xml` file, it is automatically scanned for CDI beans. If not, you can explicitly mark it to be scanned by adding this to your main application's `application.properties`:

```
quarkus.index-dependency.MYDEPENDENCY.group-id=xyz
quarkus.index-dependency.MYDEPENDENCY.artifact-id=common
```